# Change colour of swipe-to-delete background in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have been trying to change the colour of the background of the swipe to delete button in my tableview. I took a look at some Objective-C examples but I haven't been able to translate them into Swift.

This is my code at the moment:

```
    var cellDeleteBackground = UIView()
    cellDeleteBackground.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    cell.editingAccessoryView = cellDeleteBackground
```

I have this in cellForRowAtIndexPath but at the moment it is crashing with error 'terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException'

Could this code be interfering?

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
            if tableView == self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView {
                UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None
            } else {
            var valueToRemove: AnyObject! = unformatted.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)

            if images.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSObject == 0 {
                totalSpendingsCounter = totalSpendingsCounter - Double(valueToRemove as NSNumber)
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setDouble(totalSpendingsCounter, forKey: "spendingsCounter")
            } else if images.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSObject == 1 {
                totalCreditCounter = totalCreditCounter - Double(valueToRemove as NSNumber)
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setDouble(totalCreditCounter, forKey: "creditCounter")
            }

            currencyDouble = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().doubleForKey("currencyCounter")
            currentBudgetCalculation = currencyDouble + totalCreditCounter - totalSpendingsCounter

            newTransactionEntered = true

            var formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
            formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
            formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale() // This is the default
            var formattedNumberCurrent = formatter.stringFromNumber(currentBudgetCalculation)

            var defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.AffordIt")
            defaults.setObject(formattedNumberCurrent, forKey: "currentBudgetWidget")
            defaults.setObject(newTransactionEntered, forKey: "new")

            values.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            images.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            names.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            dates.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            unformatted.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            notes.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)

            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(names, forKey: "names")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(values, forKey: "values")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(dates, forKey: "dates")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(unformatted, forKey: "unformatted")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(images, forKey: "images")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(notes, forKey: "notes")

            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is how you can customise swipe-to-delete in iOS8:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {
    var deleteButton = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Delete", handler: { (action, indexPath) in
        self.tableView.dataSource?.tableView?(
            self.tableView,
            commitEditingStyle: .Delete,
            forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath
        )

        return
    })

    deleteButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    return [deleteButton]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response however this also seems to crash my app with the same error. I've updated my question with some more code in case it's an issue.

Comment: More info about exception is needed. Make sure you have breakpoint on exceptions: http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions

Comment: Turns out that it was unrelated to the code you posted and it works fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Kirsteins, how can I keep the default title, so that it shows accordingly to the localization language?

Answer (score 5):

Below the code updated for Swift 4, Xcode 9:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let deleteButton = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
        self.tableView.dataSource?.tableView!(self.tableView, commit: .delete, forRowAt: indexPath)
        return
    }
    deleteButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    return [deleteButton]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Custom swipe to delete (background colour as black) for iOS 14 as UITableViewRowAction is deprecated this uses UIContextualAction, I couldn't find a good example.

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
     
    let delete = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { [self] (action, view, completion) in
        
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            
            deleteGoalCell(indexPath: indexPath)
            
            goals.remove(at: indexPath.section)
            
            let indexSet = IndexSet(arrayLiteral: indexPath.section)
            
            tableView.deleteSections(indexSet, with: .fade)

        } else {
            
            deleteTaskcell(indexPath: indexPath)
            
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.4) {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            
        }
        
            completion(true)
        }
    
        delete.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
     
        let config = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [delete])
        config.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
     
        return config
    }
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes